# Change user roles based on profile field

Tags: 7, entities, users

I have an field role_type with values - 0,1,2...

And I need to add role X to all users who have role_type = 2?

How can I do that? Rules? SQL?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write a little module.

1. `db_select()` all users with that role_type entry
2. `user_load()` them and `user_save()` them with updated `$user->roles[]`

Maybe this thread [HOWTO assign a user to a role programatically](https://drupal.org/node/28379) on drupal.org can give you a deeper insight.